# how to get all images SRC inside grid-view in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, imagebutton

i have grid-view display 3 images the first 1  was deleted i want to loop through grid-view images and put it's src into array but ignore images that deleted 
this image  display what i really encountered

[image: my gridview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
$('#container').find('img,[type=image]').each(function() {
    arr.push(this.src); // stores the absolute src
//  arr.push($(this).attr('src')); // stores the original HTML attribute
});
```

Comment: thanks 4 replay i set your code inside my button click function and after it  alert(arr[0]); is undefined why??

Comment: Did you declare the `arr` outside your button click function? Without some actual code from you I'm just guessing at what will work.

Comment: this my code  var arr = [];
            $("#btnNext2").click(function () {

               
                $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_GvImages').find('image').each(function () {
                    arr.push(this.src); // stores the absolute src
                 
                });
                alert(arr[0]);         });

Comment: `.find('img')` not `'.find('image')`

Comment: both img or image appear undefined i use image as i am asp.net and use image-button control that generated as type= image in html

Comment: Well, that's why you need to post your HTML instead. Updated my answer.